# How to find (partially) moved contents, when script crashes

Tags: unix

I'm fairly new to unix. One of our new scripts went wrong and it tried to moved contents of huge directory on Network storage to a local directory (which actually didn't exist). The script failed giving error because of space limitation and now I don't see those contents anywhere (nowhere in old/new directory). Is there anyway to find those contents?

uname -a : 
Linux abc.com 2.6.9-22.20.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Nov 18 03:04:44 EST 2005 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Command
mv /home/user/apps  /local/app/contents

Thanks,
Prabhjot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU mv will not remove source files where the destination could not be (completely) written. In this sense it is 'atomic'

So if you're missing stuff, it will be due to another step you did.

Perhaps you can retrace what you did by doing

```
history | less
```